# Error in performing transect in ambur R?

Tags: shapefile, r

I'm trying to filter a transect, window size is 5 and filter individual baselines is set to 0. I select the transect shapefile, then the inner baseline shapefile and it gives me this error.

```
Error in SpatialLinesDataFrame(shape.prep2, trandata) : row.names of data and 
Lines IDs do not match.
```

I did everything correct up to this point, add fields to shapefiles, construct transects, stuck on filter transects. Anyone know how to fix this error or knows what it means?

The syntax for SpatialLinesDataFrame is

```
function (sl, data, match.ID = TRUE)
{
if (is.character(match.ID)) {
    row.names(data) = data[, match.ID[1]]
    match.ID = TRUE
}
if (match.ID) {
    Sl_IDs <- sapply(slot(sl, "lines"), function(x) slot(x, 
        "ID"))
    data_IDs <- row.names(data)
    mtch <- match(Sl_IDs, data_IDs)
    if (any(is.na(mtch))) 
        stop("row.names of data and Lines IDs do not match")
    if (length(unique(mtch)) != length(Sl_IDs)) 
        stop("row.names of data and Lines IDs do not match")
    data <- data[mtch, , drop = FALSE]
}
if (nrow(data) != length(sl@lines)) 
    stop("length of data.frame does not match number of Lines elements")
new("SpatialLinesDataFrame", sl, data = data)
}
<environment: namespace:sp>
```

not too familiar with code sorry. The error is happening because one of those if statements. Looking at the documentation on the R website I see that shape.prep2 is the object in SpatialLines class and trandata is an object in the data.frame class. "object of class data.frame; the number of rows in data should equal the number of Lines elements in sl." It must be something wrong with one of the shapefiles.

Comment: show your code plz.

Comment: There really isn't any code I just load the ambur package then type > library(ambur)
> ambur.gui() and the rest is done in the gui with the error popping up in the console

Comment: Contact me at cjackson@georgiasouthern.edu and I can help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, if this question is still open, but the error should be fixed by simply setting `match.ID` to `FALSE`.

```
SpatialLinesDataFrame(sl, data, match.ID = FALSE)
```